# Scale down images in SO question

Tags: support, images

I would like to include an image in a question I'm asking on StackOverflow. However it is a large image and takes up more space than I'd like it to. I'd like to scale it down a bit without having to create a new image

I tried to use an img tag, but once I added a `style`, `height`, or `width` attribute it hid the image

Is there a way to scale down the image once the link is added in the question?

Comment: Scale it down before uploading it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to use `width`, you [must put it **after** the `src` and surround it with double quotes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/180276) Example (using your profile picture):

Code:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTPK.jpg" width="50">
```

Result:

> [image]

Code:

```
<img width="50" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTPK.jpg">
```

Result:

> 

---

Also note that if your image is hosted by imgur, you can put an `s`, `m`, or `l` before the extension (for small, medium, and large respectively):

```
![](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwTPKs.jpg)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Curious that I couldn't find this solution anywhere else

Comment: @Zeaklous http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/180276