# Scale between the imgur m & l image modificators

Tags: feature-request, images, imgur, image-size-modifiers

[This feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195307/421565) scales images down **without having to use HTML tags**. It's a great idea but anything below "l" is instantly too small.
I get that it's supposed to be 100% then 50% then 25%, but it's such a big cut, especially on the UX board, where you need to see some details on the screenshot.

---

For example here:

[image]

---

Now I add the "m" modifier, **expecting it to be slightly smaller but not super small.**

[image]

---

Adding "s" results in this:

[image]

---

So both m and s are basically unusable. Is there something in-between m and l?
 **Like 75%?**

---

**Edit:** Since it's an imgur thing that we can't influence, is there a way to get "75% width" with the HTML tag and not having to worry about the exact pixels?

Comment: Good suggestion, but it's something imgur have to do, and I doubt they're going to ever do it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Damn, I was somehow thinking it was SE's feature. You're right.

Comment: Nope. SE just using API written by imgur to upload the images, the processing and scaling are 100% done on imgur side.

Comment: Related [Is the continuing absence of Imgur resizing for new images still temporary, or permanent? ETA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/315004/303080) and also [The Stack Imgur service is no longer resizing images correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314028/303080) for alternatives and workarounds.

Comment: @uhoh Damn, started reading those and ended up on discovering the dark side of StackExchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317011/what-are-the-effective-communication-channels-for-effecting-change-to-se?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Big_Chair As organizations of humans go, this one is pretty good.